# PowerBi create column of distinct Year and Month

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi I am trying to create a table with the distinct year and month values from a column in another table. I can do month or year individually I cant seem to figure out how to get both. Currently I use:

`date=Distinct(Sheet1[date].[Year])`

to get year and

`date=Distinct(Sheet1[date].[Month])`

to get distinct months. Is there a way to get distinct years and months like Jan-2015,Feb-2015....? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way I used Format to make a mmm yy date column on my first table then i just grab distinct values from it.